# Concatenating elements in list of list in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have:

```
df1 = [['10103', 'Baldwin, C', 'SFEN'], ['10115', 'Wyatt, X', 'SFEN']]
```

What would be the best way to concatenate the items within so that I could get something like:

```
[['10103 - Baldwin, C', 'SFEN'], ['10115 - Wyatt, X', 'SFEN']]
```

If I try something like

```
for i in df1:
    df1[0:1] = [' - '.join(df1[0:1])]
```

I get `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`.

Comment: `join` take list of string, you are passing list of list of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same way as yours,

```py
>>> df1 = [['10103', 'Baldwin, C', 'SFEN'], ['10115', 'Wyatt, X', 'SFEN']]
>>> for i, item in enumerate(df1):
...     df1[i] = [' - '.join(item[:2]), item[2]]
...
>>> df1
[['10103 - Baldwin, C', 'SFEN'], ['10115 - Wyatt, X', 'SFEN']]
```

Another way to go,

```py
>>> df1 = [['10103', 'Baldwin, C', 'SFEN'], ['10115', 'Wyatt, X', 'SFEN']]
>>> df1 = [[' - '.join([item1, item2]), item3] for item1, item2, item3 in df1]
>>> df1
[['10103 - Baldwin, C', 'SFEN'], ['10115 - Wyatt, X', 'SFEN']]
```